# Can I use ternary operator with a lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda, automapper

I am trying to understand if I can use ternary operators within a lambda expression.

For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Address MyAdd {get; set;}
}
```

I then want to do something like this:

```
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
        {
            c.CreateMap<foo, MyFoo>()
            .ForMember(x => x.ID, m => m.MapFrom(a => a.ID))
            .ForMember(x => x.Name, m => m.MapFrom(a => a.Name))
            .ForMember(x => x.Add1, m => m.MapFrom(a => (a.MyAdd != null) ? a.MyAdd.Line1 : string.Empty));
        });
```

However I get the error:

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type
```

Comment: Try `ResolveUsing` instead of `MapFrom`.  Note that the duplicate question creates a new method, but you can just use a lambda.

Comment: The answer to the question per the title is 'yes, you can', but AutoMapper doesn't support such an Expression in this method.  You could just leave as `a => a.MyAdd.Line1`, as AutoMapper will handle the null properties for you.